# Run a bash script before running a Maven goal in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: bash, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven project that requires a bash script to be run before running "mvn clean install". When I use the terminal (I am on a Mac) I can easily run the script first and then do "mvn clean install". However, that is not the case when I try to build the project in IDEA. I created a Maven configuration that runs clean and install, but I need to tell IDEA to run the bash script before doing Maven stuff.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an [external tool](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-third-party-tools.html) to run bash with your script as a parameter. In the Maven Run configuration, **Before launch** section add this tool via the **Run External Tool** option.

Comment: Well that kind of worked. Before I was trying to write a command instead of choosing the bash script as a program in Run External Tool window. But now my script did not work because IDEA does not recognize JAVA_HOME although it is set in .bash_profile and environment.plist. I will accept this answer because the problem I have now is something else. Thank you.

Comment: You should use `bash` as the program and `--login` in the parameters to run in the login shell and inherit the environment. Another workaround is to start IDEA from Terminal: `open -a /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 12.app/`.